# Using Selenium with Java - can't get to recognize the element (in table)

Tags: java, selenium

I've been on stack overflow all day trying to hunt down the answer to this problem. I feel like I've gotten close but no matter what I do I still cannot get the program to pass. Here is what I am trying to do:

I have an online calendar that goes by week. Each week is clickable and changes the schedule to match that week. This is what the specific row I am trying to click on  looks like:

```
 <tr align="right" class="Calendar" id="Week5" valign="bottom"
     onmouseover="highlightRow( 5, 'high' );" onmouseout="highlightRow(5, 'low' );"
 onclick="selectRow( 5 );" bgcolor="#ccffcc"> 

                        <td>25</td>
                        <td>26</td>
                        <td>27</td>
                        <td>28</td>
                        <td>29</td>
                        <td>30</td>
                        <td>31</td>
                        <td></td>
                      </tr>
```

So I recognize that this is a mouseover and it doesn't become clickable until you hover on it (right?) No matter what I do, I can't get it to recognize Week5 as a clickable element. I tried adding this:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
        WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("Week5")));
```

But it still tells me it can't find Week5 as the element. I also tried this

```
   Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
            builder.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.id("Week5"))).click().build().perform();
```

I feel like I am getting close, but the big problem is I can't get it to recognize that element. I tried using xpath for a table, but that didn't work either. Maybe I didn't do it right. Can someone help this n00b with no very little formal computer science training?

Thanks,
Scott

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following locator

```
By.xpath("//tr[contains(@id, 'Week5')]")
```

Also, check that element with current locator is first on web page! 
Hope, that it will help, for more information about answer on you question, please, send me link on webpage, with which you are working now.

Comment: Hey thanks for the try. It didn't work - still says "unable to locate element," presumably because it doesn't show it as available until you mouse over it. I would love to send a link on webpage, but it is for the internal website at work - you would need to work here to be able to access it... I appreciate your help!